# Pandas: explode a column into multiple rows

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Require some assistance in splitting a field based on regex in Pandas & creating a Dataframe.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1129 | 19-APR-2021 | Zip Code Details: City: Huntsville_Alabama , Zip: 35808 , 801thru816 City: Anchorage_Alaska , Zip: 99506 , 501thru524 |
| 1139 | 20-APR-2021 | Zip Code Details: City: Miami_Florida , Zip: 33128 , 124thru190 City: Atlanta_Georgia , Zip: 30301 , 301thru381 |

In one of the column C,  multiple City & Zip Code details need to be extracted and normalized in
the below format :

| No | Date | City | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1129 | 19-APR-2021 | Huntsville_Alabama | 35808 |
| 1129 | 19-APR-2021 | Anchorage_Alaska | 99506 |
| 1139 | 20-APR-2021 | Miami_Florida | 33128 |
| 1139 | 20-APR-2021 | Atlanta_Georgia | 30301 |

My re.findall expression is as below & works fine :

```
city_regex_extract = r" [a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]*\_[a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]*"    (https://regex101.com/r/VM8oFF/1)
zip_regex_extract = r"[0-9]{5}"                            (https://regex101.com/r/oBYJZX/1)
```

Below is the code so far, however unable to add Zip field to the same.

```
import pandas as pd
import json, re, sys, time


df = pd.DataFrame({
   'No': ['1129', '1139'],
   'Date': ['19-APR-2021','20-APR-2021'],
   'C': ['Zip Code Details: City: Huntsville_Alabama , Zip: 35808 , 801thru816  City: Anchorage_Alaska , Zip: 99506 , 501thru524','Zip Code Details: City: Miami_Florida , Zip: 33128 , 124thru190  City: Atlanta_Georgia , Zip: 30301 , 301thru381'] 
})


city_regex_extract = r" [a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]*\_[a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]*"
zip_regex_extract = r"[0-9]{17}"


df['City'] =  [re.findall(city_regex_extract, str(x)) for x in df['C']]
df['Zip'] =  [re.findall(zip_regex_extract, str(x)) for x in df['C']]

df = (df
.set_index(['No','Date'])['City']
.apply(pd.Series)
.stack()
.reset_index()
.drop('level_2', axis=1)
.rename(columns={0:'City'}))

print(df)
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't even need regex library in my oppinion, pandas has regex included, therefore you can split on:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].str.split(' City: ').str[1:]
df = df.explode('C')
df[['City','Zip']] = df['C'].str.split(' , Zip: | , ', expand=True).iloc[:,:2]

print(df)

     No         Date                City    Zip
0  1129  19-APR-2021  Huntsville_Alabama  35808
0  1129  19-APR-2021    Anchorage_Alaska  99506
1  1139  20-APR-2021       Miami_Florida  33128
1  1139  20-APR-2021     Atlanta_Georgia  30301
```

The `expand=True` parameter allows to retrieve multiple columns at once. The `.iloc[]` is used to select whcih values to use after the split occured.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, however I am unable to get 4 records . only Anchorage_Alaska & Atlanta_Georgia are retrieved.

Comment: @pats4u oh, you were right, fixed it. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

#### [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html)

```
s = df['C'].str.extractall(r'City:\s*(?P<City>[^,]+?)\s*,\s*Zip:\s*(?P<Zip>\d+)')
df[['No', 'Date']].join(s.droplevel(1))
```

---

```
     No         Date                City    Zip
0  1129  19-APR-2021  Huntsville_Alabama  35808
0  1129  19-APR-2021    Anchorage_Alaska  99506
1  1139  20-APR-2021       Miami_Florida  33128
1  1139  20-APR-2021     Atlanta_Georgia  30301
```

**Regex details:**

- `City:` : Matches the characters `City:` literally
- `\s*` : Matches zero or more whitespace characters
- `(?P<City>[^,]+?)`: First named capturing group

  - `[^,]+?`: Matches any character expect `,` one or more times but as few times as possible
- `\s*,\s*` : Matches zero or more space followed by comma followed by zero or more spaces
- `Zip:` : Matches the characters `Zip:` literally
- `\s*` : Matches zero or more whitespace characters
- `(?P<Zip>\d+)`: Second named capturing group

  - `\d+`: Matches a digit one or more times

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/i07JS0/1)

Comment: Thanks Shubham . However I am unable to get the above output. Not sure if I missed something, below is the output : 
     No         Date                                                  C
0  1129  19-APR-2021  Zip Code Details: City: Huntsville_Alabama , Z...
1  1139  20-APR-2021  Zip Code Details: City: Miami_Florida , Zip: 3...

Comment: How many rows are you getting after using the above approach 2 or 4?

Comment: I am able to view only 2 records without any extraction of City or Zip.

Comment: `df[['No', 'Date']].join(s.droplevel(1))` is not a `inplace` operation you have to assign it back to some variable. For example `out = df[['No', 'Date']].join(s.droplevel(1))` now check the value of `out`

Answer (score 1):

Try `.explode()` on `City` and `Zip`, followed by `reset_index()`, and finally joining both explode results on index

```
df.explode('City').reset_index()[['No', 'Date', 'City']]\
    .join(df.explode('Zip').reset_index()[['Zip']])
```